# How to open in a link in a new tab when embedded in an object

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, underscore.js

I am working with data that when targeted like this:
javascript

```
var infoUrl=misc[11].Value;
```

html

```
<%infoUrl%>
```

Returns this:

```
<a href="url">This is the clickable description<a/>
```

The link and text display just fine from this but I want to have the link open in in a new tab. I have tried things like:

```
<%infoUrl%>_.blank
window.open(infoUrl)
```

But none of these seem to work. How can I get this to open in a new tab?

Comment: Seems like your question is missing some stuff

Comment: Yes sorry I pressed enter before finish. It should be done now.